Specify cache threshold per function in flask caching (clear old value when function is executed)
The default behaviour of flask-caching when using memoize is to execute the function if the specified timeout has expired, then return and save the new result. However, the now outdated (previously cached) result is not removed. This is ok for most applications but becomes a problem if the cached result is large.
flask-caching exposes CACHE_THRESHOLD (https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to control this behaviour by specifying how many files in total will be kept. Setting this to 1 should keep only 1 item in the cache, so only the function that was executed most recently will be allowed to keep the copy.
Is there any way to control this per function? Ideally I have some functions where I don't care if the items are kept (as the size is not a problem) but others where the return value is so large that I want to delete the old cached value as soon as the function is executed again after the timeout has expired.
I know there is a method delete_memoized to do that on a function basis but if I use this to manually clear the cache I need to know whether this has expired or not, and I'm not sure if there's a way to do that (besides the fact that this logic is already implemented on the flask-caching side so I don't really see the necessity to reinvent the wheel for something like this).

Can you provide a [example] so that we can better understand your problem?
